# Error con método model.predict

Tags: python, numpy, keras, dataset

Estoy leyendo un archivo csv para crear un modelo  (Sequential), sin embargo al querer usar dicho modelo para predecir con

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_33" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 8), found shape=(None, 11)

Tengo en resumen, el siguiente código:

```
#Crear MLP en Keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Reshape
from keras.metrics import accuracy
import numpy
```

Luego de cargar los datos:

```
#creamos el modelo
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=150, batch_size=20, verbose=0)

predictions = model.predict(x)
```

El error viene aquí:

```
z = [[6.2,22,1,2,2,2,9.1,4,3,5,3],
 [6.2,20,12,2,3,2,9.8,4,3,4,3],
 [7.2,4.4,2,4,5,9,10,2,9.3,1,9]]

predictions = model.predict(z)
```

¿Cómo podría predecir en base a un arreglo sabiendo que tengo un modelo previamente entrenado?

Comment: Tu arreglo es de 11 elementos, no de 8, o lo modificas a 8 o cambias el input del modelo a 11

Answer (score 0):

En tu primera capa, cuando indicas el input, escribiste 8, mientras que la lista que tienes de datos son inputs de 10. Si el error lo obtienes al intentar predecir es porque posiblemente estés entrenando con 8 y ahora intentas predecir con 10 ó que aunque entrenes con 10 solo utilice los 8 primeros elementos.

La conclusión es que si quieres usar inputs de 10 elementos en la primera capa tienes que escribir input_dim=10

```
#creamos el modelo
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=150, batch_size=20, verbose=0)

predictions = model.predict(x)
```